# Switch camera control smoothly in three.js

Tags: three.js

I use `OrbitControls` control camera. Chose a visual angle, copy `camera.position` and `camera.rotation`. Then create another camera use `pointLockControl` ,use copy data to set new `camera.position` and `camera.rotation`.But new camera rotation and translate very odd.I think new control Influenceed because of copy data.I do not know why.

```
keyControl.getObject().rotation.copy(MKY.Camera.current.rotation);
keyControl.getObject().position.copy(MKY.Camera.current.position);
orbitControl.enabled = false;
keyControl.enabled = true;
MKY.Camera.current = keyControlCamera;
```

I think old camera rotation and translation influence new camera rotation and translation,but i do not know why.